# Flex multimedia file management

Tags: apache-flex, file-management

Just I have started learning flex for my project. This is project is a kind image, video, audio file management which is accessible from local hard drive like adding, deleting etc..

I heard that Air is doing this kind of work. But our client asking that the project should run only on the browser not like a application.

I have searched lot of tuts. But I haven't get much tutorials. please give me some suggestion to get this type o tutorial.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Browser applications cannot manipulate local hard disk contents, regardless of their type - Flash, or JavaScript, or Silverlight - security model is similar for all of them. Try to persuade your client with seamless install of AIR applications (google "AIR badge install".)

Comment: Yeah, accessing local files through a web app would be a *huge* security risk.  The only way this is possible is if your app uses `FileReference.browse()` but that's normally to just get one file or directory.